# Recaptcha request from production server

Tags: angularjs, post, cors

I am using CORS plugin for **chrome** and it works fine when uses local machine, but in production server the error occurs:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access.

I understand the problem, that domain server different from domain to send request, also I understand that all users will not add CORS plugin to avoid chrome specific features.

So how do I can off checking for **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** for concrete post request? Use **Angular** to send request.

```
return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        headers:{
          'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        data: $.param(data)
      });
```

I need to avoid this error on prod server.

Comment: `So how do I can off checking` please make this easy to understand for non-native speakers - is this _can_ as in _you can tuna-fish (but you can't tune a fish)?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue a few days ago and searched everywhere for a response. From what I gathered, the only way to do  a cross-domain AJAX request is if you have control of both of the servers hosting each domain. This way you can add the necessary headers in the HTTP requests to allow for cross-domain requests. If you don't have control of both servers, you can POST to a PHP script on your server that can then POST externally and return the info you need. That's how I resolved my issue anyway. hope it helps!